# How to split DataTable rows using a for loop?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataTable like this:

[image: Original DataTable]

And I want to write a `for` loop that shows debit and credit line on its own separate line like this:

[image: Result]

Here is my unfinished code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("DEBIT", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("CREDIT", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("AMOUNT", typeof(double));

dt.Rows.Add("Debit1", "Credit1", 10);
dt.Rows.Add("Debit2", "Credit2", 8);
dt.Rows.Add("Debit3", "Credit3", 12);

for (int i=1; i <= dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    //The first image (datatable) has three debit and credit lines are showing on the same line. Normally the debit line and credit line are showing on its own separate lines.
    //With above given datatable I want to construct for loop that shows three debit lines and three credit lines as demonstrated in the second image. In this case it shows 6 lines
}
```

I would much appreciate it if you could help me with this.

Comment: Hmmm. `dt.Rows.Add("Debit1", "", 10);`, `dt.Rows.Add("", "Credit1", 10)` ...

Comment: I'm guessing the DataTable is already filled with data and the code in question is just for demonstraion. Otherwise yes, the OP should fill debit and credit rows separately from the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Steps:**

- Start the loop in reverse (so you can easily insert rows).
- Create a new row for the credit and fill it with the relevant data.
- Remove the credit data from the original row.
- Insert the new column in the position following the original row.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var row = dt.Rows[i];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row["CREDIT"].ToString()))
    {
        var creditRow = dt.NewRow();
        creditRow["CREDIT"] = row["CREDIT"];
        creditRow["AMOUNT"] = row["AMOUNT"];
        row["CREDIT"] = string.Empty;
        dt.Rows.InsertAt(creditRow, i + 1);
    }
}
```

**[Try it online](https://rextester.com/KEUZ59153)**.

Comment: Dear 41686d6564, Thanks very much for your answer. How do I display Console.WriteLine() in the same for loop as per second image?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want to print the DataTable in a tabular format in the Console? If so, check the `PrintDataTable()` method in the link above. I'm not sure why you want to do that though. I only used it to demonstrate the result. Are you creating a Console Application?

Comment: Just saw PrintDataTable(). Thanks once again for helping me resolve the problem. Have a nice day.